# Vuejs: Access a Parent Component Method from Child Component

Tags: vue.js

I can't access the parent method from a child component. I did what the [official document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html) stated.

Parent template:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-sheet height="100vh">
      <v-sheet height="100vh" class="overflow-y-auto">
        <div ref="ComponentDisplay" :is="currentComponent"></div>
      </v-sheet>
      <DrawerComponent></DrawerComponent>
    </v-sheet>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Dashboard',
  data: function () {
    return {
      currentComponent: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    displayComponent (component) {
      this.currentComponent = component
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

DrawerComponent:

```
export default {
  name: 'DrawerComponent',
  methods: {
    exit: function () {
      logout()
    },
    swapComponent: function (component) {
      this.$parent.displayComponent(this.components[component])
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    drawer: false,
    group: null,
    mini: true,
    components: {}
  }),
  watch: {
    group () {
      this.drawer = false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

At the line:

```
this.$parent.displayComponent(this.components[component])
```

the below error raises:

> TypeError: this.$parent.displayComponent is not a function

Comment: You misunderstood the Vue component communication model. Components are fed data via props, and communicate to the outside world only via events. The whole idea of components is encapsulation, that is, a component doesn't know anything besides itself.

Comment: @connexo, Yeah, I've just started using `Vue` and don't know a lot of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a good practice to use `$parent`, but instead of that you could use `emit` to send an event from the child component to run some method in parent one :

in the Child component emit the event with your payload :

```js
    swapComponent: function (component) {
      this.$emit("swap-component",this.components[component])
    }
```

in parent one:

```html
 <DrawerComponent @swap-component="displayComponent"></DrawerComponent>
```

and change `div` to `component` in

```html
<div ref="ComponentDisplay" :is="currentComponent"></div>
```

Comment: The error is gone but something else is raised. `[Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'componentInstance')"
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'componentInstance')`

Comment: try out `<component ref="ComponentDisplay" :is="currentComponent??'div'"></component>` instead of `<div ref="ComponentDisplay" :is="currentComponent"></div>`

Comment: I fixed it, I just registered the components globally instead of local components.

Comment: If you use Vue 3? you may INJECT any Methods from Parent in Child and call it anywhere. (Composition API is preferable)

Comment: the logic is also valid for composition api just use `emit` from `setup(props,{emit})` instead of `this.$emit`